# Cakephp: combine input values to create hidden name input

Tags: cakephp, concatenation

I've searched high and low for a solution but can't seem to get this figured out. What I'm trying to do is upon adding a product, I want the name field to be populated from the inputs in the form. So the name would include the values the user selects for type_id,category_id and subcategory_id. Does anyone know of a way to accomplish this?

Add product View page

```
    <fieldset>
    <legend><?php echo __('Add Product'); ?></legend>
<?php
    echo $this->Form->input('type_id');
    echo $this->Form->input('category_id', array('label' => 'Vendor'));
    echo $this->Form->input('subcategory_id', array('label' => 'Model'));
    echo $this->Form->input('location', array('label' => 'Location'));
    echo $this->Form->input('sku', array('label' => 'Asset Tag'));
    echo $this->Form->input('mac');
    echo $this->Form->input('description', array('label' => 'Notes'));
    echo $this->Form->input('name', array( 'value' => ['type_id']['category_id']  , 'type' => 'hidden'));
    //echo $this->Form->input('cost');
    // echo $this->Form->input('Tag');
    ?>
    </fieldset>
```

Product controller add function

```
    public function add() {
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $this->Product->create();
        if ($this->Product->save($this->request->data)) {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The product has been saved'));
            $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The product could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
        }
    }
    $subcategories = $this->Product->Subcategory->find('list',array('order'=>'Subcategory.name asc'));
    $categories = $this->Product->Category->find('list',array('order'=>'Category.name asc'));
    $types = $this->Product->Type->find('list',array('order'=>'Type.name asc'));
    $this->set(compact('subcategories', 'categories', 'types'));

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to do it the way you are trying to do it, you would have to use client-side javascript to update the input value "on-the-fly", but that's not very safe and can easily be messed with. It would make much more sense to drop the name input altogether and just handle this in the [beforeSave](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/callback-methods.html#beforesave) method of your Product model (or alternatively by defining the name value in your Controller just before saving).

```
public function beforeSave($options = array()) {
    // Generate the name based on type and category
    $this->data['Product']['name'] = $this->data['Product']['type_id'] .
                                     $this->data['Product']['category_id'];

    return true;
}
```

**Update based on your comment.**

In order to get the names, just find those names (assuming your models are associated) and define those:

```
public function beforeSave($options = array()) {
    // Get the type name
    $type = $this->Type->field('name', array(
        // Set the condition for the field
        'Type.id' => $this->data['Product']['type_id']
    ));

    // Get the category name
    $category = $this->Category->field('name', array(
        // Set the condition for the field
        'Category.id' => $this->data['Product']['category_id']
    ));

    // Generate the name based on type and category
    $this->data['Product']['name'] = $type . $category;

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Awesome thank you! This worked almost exactly as I wanted it to. Do you know if it's possible to substitute the associated type_id and category_id with their respective names instead of id?